# Ubuntu cannot find package 'saods9'

Tags: 12.04, apt, installed-programs

I am trying to install DS9, but after trying several approaches, the command line still sends me the same answer.

First, I run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`. After both I enter `sudo apt-get install saods9` and what the terminal gives me back is that

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package saods9 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'saods9' has no installation candidate
```

Does anyone know what I should do to get it installed? Thank you.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I have tried searching `SAOImage DS9` and it gives me nothing back. Also, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`saods9` is only supported on Ubuntu 14.04 and later. You may be able to install it on 12.04 using a PPA from [here](https://launchpad.net/~olebole/+archive/ubuntu/astro-precise).

Comment: look here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/saods9 you might do better if you install from source code.

Comment: Thank you, I will try installing it from the source code then!